# Why does times give me the same output after sleep(5) in C

Tags: c, timer, sleep

I have the problem that I want to measure the time of a function. I call timer at the beginning and at the end of the function but it returns the same value even though when I call sleep(5).

Here the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/times.h>

void function_to_time(void);

int main(void) { 
double clockticks, cticks;
clock_t tcend, tcstart;
struct tms tmend, tmstart;

if ((clockticks = (double) sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK)) == -1) {
  perror("Failed to determine clock ticks per second");
  return 1;
}
printf("The number of ticks per second is %f\n", clockticks);
if (clockticks == 0) {
  fprintf(stderr, "The number of ticks per second is invalid\n");
  return 1;
}
if ((tcstart = times(&tmstart)) == -1) {
  perror("Failed to get start time");
  return 1;
}
function_to_time(); 
if ((tcend = times(&tmend)) == -1) {
  perror("Failed to get end times");
  return 1;
}
cticks = tmend.tms_utime + tmend.tms_stime 
         - tmstart.tms_utime - tmstart.tms_stime;
printf("Total CPU time for operation is %f seconds\n", cticks/clockticks); 
if ((tcend <= tcstart) || (tcend < 0) || (tcstart < 0)) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Tick time wrapped, couldn't calculate fraction\n");
  return 1;
}
printf("Fraction of CPU time used is %f\n", cticks/(tcend - tcstart));
return 0;
} 

void function_to_time()
{
    sleep(5);   

}
```

Please note that I have to use the timer function.
I'm using MAC OS X 10.10 and in a virtual machine Ubuntu 14.04 on a MacBook Pro.

Thanks, Best Regards
Armin

Comment: What is the granularity of the timer function you are using, compared to your test function's run time?

Comment: Because you aren't using the CPU in either system or user space when your code is asleep.

Comment: Ok thanks for pointing this out. I have the same problem when I use a while loop inside function_to_time. This should spend user time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because times doesn't necessarily give millisecond resolution. It gives times in increments of "CLK_TCK's of a second"

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/times.3.html

EDIT:

@Armin, The function would have to run for more than `1/CLK_TCK` seconds. But after a closer look, I think @JonathanLeffler has it more right. The the fields of the struct returned that apply directly to the calling process are listed as:

```
tms_utime //The CPU time charged for the execution of user instructions.
tms_stime //The CPU time charged for execution by the system on behalf of the process.
```

So it's different from the wall-clock style timings I'm used to using. The process would have to be actively running (not sleeping) for more than `1/CLK_TCK` seconds between calls to `times` before you will see it tick.

Comment: So the function must execute more than one second?

Comment: The was really that the function consumed too less time. Thank you!